# Flex Fileupload not working

Tags: apache-flex, file-io, file-upload, flex4

I have now ran into Flex Fileupload problem on ssl as many others have. I simply get an IOError, no other information as to what caused the error was given, ssl handshake or something else. How do I nail down the cause of the error? I tried using the ';jsessionid=' trick, still no luck.

FYI, I am running on local https server, with self signed cert. Everthing works fine without ssl. With ssl, it only works on IE (FF, Chrome, Safari fails on https). With other browsers, server doesn't even get the request.

Nish

Comment: Does everything work without SSL for you?

Comment: Is it specific to some particular browser (i.e. IE)?

Comment: @Scott- yes, it does.@Maria Sakharova- it works only on IE, it doesn' on other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make self-signed certificates work with the Flex uploader, the server certificate must be signed by a Certificate Authority whose CA Certificate is then installed in Internet Explorer's **Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store**. This actually is quite easy to accomplish.

Start at **(1B) Generate your own CA (Certificate Authority)** on this web page: [Creating Certificate Authorities and self-signed SSL certificates](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html) and generate your CA Certificate and Key. Once you have these, generate your Server Certificate and Key. Create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and then sign the Server Key with the CA Certificate. Now install your Server Certificate and Key on the web server as usual, and import the CA Certificate into Internet Explorer's Trusted Root Certification Authority Store (used by the Flex uploader and Chrome as well) and into Firefox's Certificate Manager Authorities Store on each workstation that needs to access the server using the self-signed, CA-signed server key/certificate pair.

You now should not see any warning about using self-signed Certificates as the browsers will find the CA certificate in the Trust Store and verify the server key has been signed by this trusted certificate. Also in e-commerce applications like Magento, the Flex image uploader will now function in Firefox without the dreaded "Self-signed certificate" error message.

Answer (score 0):

Self signed certificates will not work with Flex file upload in non-IE browsers. You can read more about this problem here: http://b-closer.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-get-flex-file-upload-over-ssl.html.

Your only workarounds are to either use non-secure upload for non-IE browsers or to purchase a signed certificate from a CA.